# Exporting powerpivot data to csv

Tags: vba, export-to-csv, powerpivot

I have an Excel workbook with powerpivot data in Excel data model. I don't have the file used to import the data into powerpivot. My goal is to get the data out of powerpivot to a csv so I can use it in some other software.

I can't find any direct export options in powerpivot and since the data is larger than 1.1M rows it can't be pushed into Excel.

I found this VBA which appears to work for smaller files but for larger ones I get a timeout error.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportToCsv()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sQuery As String

    'Suppress alerts and screen updates
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Bind to active workbook
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Make sure the model is loaded
    wbTarget.Model.Initialize

    'Send query to the model
    sQuery = "EVALUATE 'combine 2010 - Q2 2015'"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open sQuery, wbTarget.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    Dim CSVData As String
    CSVData = RecordsetToCSV(rs, True)

    'Write to file
    Open "D:\tempMyFileName.csv" For Binary Access Write As #1
        Put #1, , CSVData
    Close #1

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

ExitPoint:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured - " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub



Public Function RecordsetToCSV(rsData As ADODB.Recordset, _
        Optional ShowColumnNames As Boolean = True, _
        Optional NULLStr As String = "") As String
    'Function returns a string to be saved as .CSV file
    'Option: save column titles

    Dim K As Long, RetStr As String

    If ShowColumnNames Then
        For K = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
            RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
        Next K

        RetStr = Mid(RetStr, 2) & vbNewLine
    End If

    RetStr = RetStr & """" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, -1, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
    RetStr = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 3)

    RecordsetToCSV = RetStr
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work without export file size restrictions by doing 1k rows at a time and using `FileSystemObject`. You'll need to add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library and Microsoft Scripting Runtime as references.

```
Option Explicit

Public FSO As New FileSystemObject

Public Sub ExportToCsv()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sQuery As String

    'Suppress alerts and screen updates
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Bind to active workbook
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Make sure the model is loaded
    wbTarget.Model.Initialize

    'Send query to the model
    sQuery = "EVALUATE <Query>"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open sQuery, wbTarget.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    Dim CSVData As String
    Call WriteRecordsetToCSV(rs, "<ExportPath>", True)

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

ExitPoint:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured - " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub



Public Sub WriteRecordsetToCSV(rsData As ADODB.Recordset, _
        FileName As String, _
        Optional ShowColumnNames As Boolean = True, _
        Optional NULLStr As String = "")
    'Function returns a string to be saved as .CSV file
    'Option: save column titles

    Dim TxtStr As TextStream
    Dim K As Long, CSVData As String

    'Open file
    Set TxtStr = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileName, True, True)

    If ShowColumnNames Then
        For K = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
            CSVData = CSVData & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
        Next K

        CSVData = Mid(CSVData, 2) & vbNewLine
        TxtStr.Write CSVData
    End If

    Do While rsData.EOF = False
        CSVData = """" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, 1000, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
        CSVData = Left(CSVData, Len(CSVData) - IIf(rsData.EOF, 3, 2))
        TxtStr.Write CSVData
    Loop

    TxtStr.Close

End Sub
```