# Excel Power Pivot export

Tags: c#, excel, vba, powerpivot

I have a good skill in VBA and c# but a very low skill in Excel so I need help for my scenario.
I have an excel xlsx with some data inside.
Data comes from a Power Pivot table.
Assuming i'm using Excel 2018, i click on "Power Pivot" bar menu, then on "Manage".
I can see 4 tables.

I need a way "programatically" export the 4 tables to a csv.
With a simple c# app, I exported the sheet but data are incomplete because of filters and so on. And I cannot operate on the source excel because it come from a remote system.
Is there a way in VBA, or in .NET to iterate EVERY cell for every Power Pivot table in an Excel file?
I wrote something like:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();

var v = xlApp.Workbooks;
xlWorkBook = v.Open(bla bla...);
var s = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
var pt = s.PivotTables[1];
```

.. now I am stuck...
I had a try opening the xlsx file from another excel file, within a Module VBA, with no luck.
Please help me :-)
TY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting powerpivot data to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166362/exporting-powerpivot-data-to-csv)

Comment: Thank Olly, but I have a bad skill in Excel. The post is without any explain.. just something like "this is my code it doesn't work". And an answer like "Try this".
How can help that post?
And, most of all, it downs't work for my case.
How have I to buil the query string?
How can I choose the table?
Thank anyway

Comment: Have you done any research? Google finds this: https://www.kasperonbi.com/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/